# Two instances referenced to the same object

Tags: python, class

I have a class that looks somthing like this:

```
class A(dict):
  info = {'num': 0}
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.setdefault('info', self.info)
```

When I'm creating instances of this class they referenced to the same object:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> 
>>> b.info['num']
0
>>> a.info['num'] = 1
>>> b.info['num']
1
>>>
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong.

#### Problems:

1. Instances of `a` and `b` are referenced to the same object.

#### Desired output:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> 
>>> b.info['num']
0
>>> a.info['num'] = 1
>>> b.info['num']
0
>>>
```

#### Question:

1. How to change the class in order to keep this "template" of `info`?
2. Why the current approuch doesn't work?

Comment: You need to make `num` an instance level object, not a class level.

Comment: In this case, if you need to have the template accessible, then in your constructor do `self.info = dict(self.info)`