# Difficulty understanding why two instances of a class share the same internal object

Tags: python

I have read the below StackOverflow questions and my situation is similar but (I think) different:

- [Two instances of class share same vairable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447164)
- [Two instances referenced to the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040466)

My class creates what is meant to be an instance-level dictionary object. However, my constructor function provides a default value for that object. When I try to make an instance of my class with the default value, it suddenly behaves like it was class-level.

```
class store_a_dict:
    def __init__(self,dict_in={"A":0}):
        self.dict = dict_in

    def increment(self):
        self.dict["A"] += 1

    def print_me(self):
        print(self.dict)

test1 = store_a_dict({"A":3})
print("Initialised test1. Now test1 contains:")
test1.print_me()
test2 = store_a_dict()
print("Initialised test2 using default input. Now test2 contains:")
test2.print_me()
test2.increment()
print("Incremented test2. Now test2 contains:")
test2.print_me()
test3 = store_a_dict()
print("Initialised test3 using default input. Now test3 contains:")
test3.print_me()
print("We haven't touched test1, and it still contains:")
test1.print_me()
```

The code output is below. My expectation was that `test3` should contain `{'A': 0}` after I initialised it using `store_a_dict()` with no inputs.

```
Initialised test1. Now test1 contains:
{'A': 3}
Initialised test2 using default input. Now test2 contains:
{'A': 0}
Incremented test2. Now test2 contains:
{'A': 1}
Initialised test3 using default input. Now test3 contains:
{'A': 1}
We haven't touched test1, and it still contains:
{'A': 3}
```

It seems like the obvious workaround is to change line 3 of my code to read `self.dict = dict_in.copy()`, but I want to understand why it works this way. Why is it perfectly happy to take in a value for `dict_in` when one is provided as part of a call to the class, and have it be isolated to the instance, but when I try to use the default value it suddenly seems to become a class-level object? Please help me understand this more deeply so I can avoid similar mistakes.

Comment: Python picked a really dumb implementation of default argument values. No other language I'm aware of made the same mistake - reevaluation on every call is the overwhelmingly dominant approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The linked thread answers my question, I believe. Do I need to do anything now that my question has been marked as a duplicate?

Comment: You can just leave the question as it is.